# how many copies of the inner function will be created

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

These days most of my work is related to js developing.

However I suddenly found that I am confused with some questions.

Check this code(I add one method to a custom class):

```
MyCustomClass.prototype.fun=function(xx){
  this.options={.....}
  function innerFun01(){}
  function innerFun02(){}
}
```

Now,use it.

```
var mcc=new MyCustomClass();
mcc.fun(xxxx);

var mcc2=new MyCustomClass();
mcc2.fun(xxxx);
```

Now,I wonder how many copies of the function "innerFun01" and "innerFun02" will be created in the memory?

I am really confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those functions will be constructed each time the function "fun" is called. (I suppose it's more correct to say that *new instances of those functions will be constructed.*)

It's OK.  Modern JavaScript runtime systems are pretty good. It's possible that the translation of the source code into ... well whatever (thunks, machine code, threaded code, ...) is done when the outer function is first parsed, so that the actual "instantiation" of the functions is really cheap.

Lots of functional languages have similar characteristics. A local Scheme function declared with a `(let ...)` or something would similarly be brought into being each time its containing function is called.

Comment: Is this a waste of memory? any idea to change them? But I do not want to define them outside,since I do not want to expose them .

Comment: It isn't really a waste of memory. They get instantiated, but then thrown out after the method 'fun' is done running. The javascript garbage collector will come along shortly thereafter and collect them up and toss 'em out.

Comment: Joe Armstrong, the Erlang luminary, responds to such worries about issues with that language by urging developers to "write the most beautiful code" that they can.  Write code that's *algorithmically* sound, and only worry about such things in extreme (unlikely) cases.

Answer (score 0):

One simple rule helps to clarify your confusion: JavaScript functions are function objects. And we all know in function body local variables are instantiated every time the function is invoked. Given the two, the answer is obvious: the inner functions are created every time the outer function is called.